# SQL Server CASE statement with multiple THEN clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen several similar questions but none cover what I need. I need to put another THEN statement after the first one. My column contains int's. When it returns NULL I need it to display a blank space, but when I try the below code, I just get '0'.

```
CASE 
    WHEN Column1 IS NULL  
    THEN ''
    ELSE Column1
END
```

If I try to put a sting after THEN then it tells me that it cannot convert it from int. I need to convert it to varchar and then change its output to a blank space afterwards, such as:

e.g.

```
CASE 
    WHEN Column1 IS NULL 
    THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), Column1)
    THEN ''
    ELSE Column1
END
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Can you give some sample data.

Comment: Case _expression_.

Comment: @SantoshJadi data would be a column for users and then Column1 which contains mostly NULL values with a few exceptions of numbers ranging from 1-4.

Comment: @jarlh apologies, I am still pretty new to coding and am still picking up on the syntax. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: A case expression returns a value, and can be used in a query. A case statement is used for conditional execution of code, for example in stored procedures (and does not return a value.)

Answer (score 4):

A `case` expression returns a single value -- with a given type.  If you want a string result, then you need to be sure that all paths in the `case` return strings:

```
CASE WHEN Column1 IS NULL  
     THEN ''
     ELSE CAST(Column1 AS VARCHAR(255))
END
```

This is more simply written using `COALESCE()`:

```
COALESCE(CAST(Column1 as VARCHAR(255)), '')
```

You cannot display an integer as a "blank" (other than using a `NULL` value).

Comment: Sorry Gordon, but as the column is integers a blank space is displayed as 0, hence why I am trying to do the conversion first and then display ''

Comment: @rob the last then returns an integer. Since INTEGER has higher priority SQL Server converts ALL branches (including the ones that contain explicit cast) back to INT. For VARCHAR to "win" there must be no integers in any branch.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @SalmanA. Looks like I will just have to remove the NULL values in post.